# Convert dictionary with both nested and non-nested items into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a following dictionary:

```
{'instance_1': {'race': {'asian': 0,
   'black': 99,
   'white': 9},
  'dominant_race': 'black',
  'region': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'w': 100, 'h': 100}},
 'instance_2': {'race': {'asian': 0,
   'black': 0,
   'white': 89},
  'dominant_race': 'white',
  'region': {'x': 6, 'y': 12, 'w': 79, 'h': 79}}}
```

and would like to convert it into pandas data frame such that each element within each item is its own column, like

| item | asian | black | white | dominant_race | x | y | w | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| instance_1 | 0 | 99 | 9 | black | 0 | 0 | 100 | 100 |
| instance_2 | 0 | 0 | 89 | white | 6 | 12 | 79 | 79 |

Using `pd.DataFrame.to_dict()` with orient=index yields the following result

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(predictions, orient='index')

            race                                 dominant_race  \
instance_1  {'asian': 0, 'black': 99....         black   
instance_2  {'asian': 0, 'black': 0.....         white   

                                            region  
instance_1    {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'w': 100, 'h': 100}  
instance_2     {'x': 6, 'y': 12, 'w': 79, 'h': 79}
```

How do I convert the dictionary so that each element within 'race' and 'region' are its own columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.apply(pd.Series)` will break the dictionaries within your cells to different columns.

Assuming that the sample above is a good representation of your real data, you can first use `pd.DataFrame().T` , and then use `concat` to combine the newly formed columns from region and race:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T # d being your sample dictionary

res = pd.concat([df['race'].apply(pd.Series),
               df['dominant_race'],
               df['region'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Which will print:

```
res
Out[262]: 
            asian  black  white dominant_race  x   y    w    h
instance_1      0     99      9         black  0   0  100  100
instance_2      0      0     89         white  6  12   79   79
```

Comment: amazing -- thank you so much!